# Trying to get clipboard data

Tags: excel, vba, clipboard

I'm trying to get clipboard data through this lines:

```
Sub GetClipboard()

  Dim objData As New MSForms.DataObject
  Dim strText

  objData.GetFromClipboard
  strText = objData.GetText()

  MsgBox strText

End Sub
```

I get the error:

> "User-Defined type not defined"

While "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" is selected in Tools> Reference!

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Add a form to your VB project - that will add the required reference.  You can remove the form and the reference will stay added.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the correct reference.
In this case for the MSForms namespace you need the Microsoft Forms Object Library (e.g. Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library reference).

On my installation of Office 2016 I do not have this library that I could reference. But as stated here (https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/tutorials/vba-copy-to-clipboard-paste-clear/) there are problems since Windows 8/10 anyway. The solution is to use the Windows API directly. Which should work on Windows 7 and newer.

In the first link there is an example only for setting data to the clipboard. You asked for retrieving data so a quick internet search revealed this example code which is described as working on Windows x86 and x86_64 and supports setting and getting data from the clipboard (https://francescofoti.com/2013/12/share-the-clipboard-with-vba-and-the-windows-api/).

I have tested the code from the second link to retrieve a string from the clipboard and it worked. I had to fix a minor thing. The `Application` object on my Office installation does not have a member called `hWndAccessApp`. One has to replace it with the default `hwnd` member:

```
Application.hWndAccessApp
```

replaced with:

```
Application.hwnd
```

Comment: Tnx for the reply, but I cant copy the code from the second link properly. When I paste it, I'll get many errors!

Comment: Above each code block you can select that it should be shown as "raw text" and "expand code". Then you there should be no problem to copy and paste it.

Comment: No luck. tried all the above options. still cant select the code!

Answer (score 0):

You  need  below

```
       set objData = New MSForms.DataObject
```